# Handling images in HTML In TextView in a different way

Tags: android, image, textview

I'm trying to show `Html` in `TextView`. And all works fine, but I want to display images in `TextView` in different way.

For example, I want each image to be in the container, which can be dragged and dropped.

Does anyone knows any way to implement this?

Thanks!

**Upd**: I can't use `WebView`, because I will show about 10-20 separate views on same `Activity` at once. And I don't think it will help me to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem.

The main idea:
Go through all spans from `Html.fromHtml(section.text)` and search for `ImageSpan`. Once it is found set all previous spans as text for one `TextView`, create `ImageView` for image, continue searching.

Code:

```
new AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    protected List<Object> doInBackground(String... params) {
        List<Object> res = new ArrayList<Object>();
        Spanned in = Html.fromHtml(section.text);

        Object[] spans = in.getSpans(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Object.class); // get all spans
        int lastImageSpanPosition = 0; // it's end position of image span
        for (int i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) { // itarete searching ImageSpan
            Object span = spans[i];

            if (span instanceof ImageSpan) {
                int spanStart = in.getSpanStart(span); // If you;ve found one

                if (lastImageSpanPosition == spanStart) 
                    continue; // check if image is first span (avoid creation of empty spans).
                res.add(new SpannableStringBuilder(in.subSequence(lastImageSpanPosition, spanStart))); // add all previous spans as a single Spannable object

                ImageSpan imageSpan = (ImageSpan) span;
                String imageUrl = imageSpan.getSource();
                if (!imageUrl.startsWith("http"))
                    imageUrl = "http:" + imageUrl;

                res.add(new ImageSpan(null, imageUrl)); // add separate span for image
                lastImageSpanPosition = in.getSpanEnd(span);
            }

            if (i < spans.length - 1 && !containsImageSpan(spans, i + 1)) { // to not lose text in the end
                res.add(new SpannableStringBuilder(in.subSequence(lastImageSpanPosition, in.getSpanEnd(spans[spans.length - 1]))));
                break;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Object> objects) {
        for (Object object : objects) {
            View v = null;

            if (object instanceof ImageSpan) { // create separate views for each span
                NetworkImageView networkImageView = new NetworkImageView(getContext());
                networkImageView.setImageUrl(((ImageSpan) object).getSource(), App.get().getImageLoader());
                v = networkImageView;
            } else {
                TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
                textView.setText((CharSequence) object);
                v = textView;
            }
            holder.sectionTextViewsContainer.addView(v);
        }

    }
}.execute(section.text);
```

EDIT: added `containsImageSpan` method

```
private boolean containsImageSpan(Object[] spans, int index) {
    for (int i = index; i < spans.length; i++) {
        if (spans[i] instanceof ImageSpan) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you please public your containsImageSpan function please ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of HTML class, I'm not sure you can achieve what you want. Take a look at
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

If you really want to use HTML I recommand you to use a webview. Otherwise, you can use native drag and drop. Check the official training: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: Thanks, for answer! I updated my question. In short, WebView does not fit for this particular situation.